# MoveFocus from one listBox to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have the Output something like Windows 8 Start Menu.

Here is screen-shot of my Output:

[image]

I have successfully got that output by getting help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150944/which-control-will-be-more-appropriate-to-the-output-shown-below) question.

XAML for achieving the below output:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}" >

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" />

                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Design_Master_TileItem}" BorderThickness="0"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
                         helpers:SingleSelectionGroup.SelectionGroup="Group">

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=lst, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, Converter={StaticResource stringToBrushConverter}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Background, Converter ={StaticResource stringToBrushConverter}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="125" Width="250">
                                <Path Data="{Binding ImageData}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                      Width="68" Height="68" Margin="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                            </TransformGroup.Children>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource spaceToNewLineConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           Margin="40,10,10,10" FontSize="24" Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So, from the above code you might have understood that Group and Ledger are two items of listbox1. and other four are the items of listbox2.

**Requirements:**

Suppose, ItemA1 is selected in listboxA.

*Case1: New Behavior*

If ListBoxA does not have any items on the right side of Item1, then when I press right arrow key the focus should move to the ItemB1 of listboxB. Likewise if ItemA2 of listboxA is selected then the focus should move to the ItemB2 of ListBoxB.

*Case2: Default Behavior*

If ListBoxA has some items on the right hand side of ItemA1, then that item should be selected by pressing right arrow key. I have this behavior by default but I don't want to disturb it. I mean while implementing Case1 I don't want to loose the default behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not say exactly, but try add this Style to `ListBox`: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}"><Style.Triggers><Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False"><Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" /></Trigger></Style.Triggers</Style>`. This means that if there are no elements in `ListBox`, he can not receive Focus.

Comment: Nope, you have mis-understood my question completely. The ListBox's ItemsPanel is set to WrapPanel with Orientation = Vertical. Now read the requirements section in question. I think you will now know what I want.

Comment: Sorry that did not understand the question again, but I had warned in advance that I can not say for sure. I think it will be hard to do, because you have one `ListBox` in DataTemplate and while working to get access to multiple `ListBox`. Yes, this can be done through a large and ugly code, and by the algorithm, which should take into account the elements on each side. Therefore, if you have an alternative I suggest to find her. If not, I'll take this challenge and I can not say exactly when it will finish. And yet, if you want me to start doing the task, please let me a link to your project.

Comment: Another question: `Likewise if ItemA2 of listboxA is selected then the focus should move to the ItemB2 of ListBoxB.` and `If ListBoxA has some items on the right hand side of ItemA1, then that item should be selected by pressing right arrow key.` - What's the difference between them? This is not the same behavior?

Comment: I have mentioned that because see the sentence after word `and` in your comment, which is the default behavior. and the sentence before `and` is what I want to achieve without loosing the default behavior. In short forget about the Requirements section all-together and keep in mind that I want the behavior just like windows 8 start screen.

Comment: Yes, If you become free then have a look at the project files below :

 Database Files : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bTmZ3S1lDM2lvdG8/edit?usp=sharing

Project : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bWDhsbHltb2VhU3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not work with Windows 8, and my studio is not open your project, because it is lower version. When there is time, I will try to reproduce it on my micro project but I can not exactly promise.

Comment: I was not able to do it and here's why. As I understand it, you need to save the previously `SelectedIndex` in the `ListBox`, then to choose his own in the next `ListBox`. So, there is no property in ItemsControl like `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem`, accordingly, we do not know which is currently selected `ListBox`, to keep it current `SelectedIndex`. As an alternative - use `ListBox` instead of the `ItemsControl`, but then there will be a general confusion about the Focus, because it can be at the same time only one control with Focus (I already tried).

Comment: It's OK, thanks for trying to help me. Can you find any alternative way to do it?

Comment: No, I already tried. For me, so I do not see anything wrong in your behavior by default.

Comment: @Vishal your current xaml code is also working only you need to add  KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"  to listbox http://prntscr.com/48gbbp try this may be it will save your  efforts for new code

Comment: @HeenaPatil Thanks, for the above comment. I have just tried what you mentioned in the comment. But I get some problems while I use your code. When I press arrow keys it looks to work fine, but 1. if first item of first listbox is seleected then, if I press left arrow key, I get a red border around that listbox. 2. If first Item of any listbox is selected andd I press up arrow key then focus goes to the control above i.e. menu is focused.

Comment: have you set focusvisualstyle to Listbox and Itemscontrol ? try setting Focusable= false to listbox and itemscontrol and remove focusvisualstyle = {x:null}..your code works perfect here.

Comment: @HeenaPatil Sorry to say, but I have already set Focusable="false". Also I don't have focusvisual style in my code. Still it does not work properly.

Comment: @Vishal For 2 :Set KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"  to ItemsControl and For 1: i dont understand why this red color border is coming is your listbox has scrollviwer..must be some another control taking focus here.

Comment: Yes, Now it works fine. But if I don't want to Cycle then what should I do? I mean if last Item is selected and I press down arrow key then I don't want to move focus to the first item.

Comment: @HeenaPatil Got it. I set KeyBoardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" on ItemsControl and it works as expected. Please post the above comments as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Please take a look at simple solution provided by Heena Patil. It might help you in future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Current xaml code  working fine here.. Please refer this link for [KeyBoardNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx)  [Keyboardnavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx)

> You need to add only **KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"** **KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"** to listbox and it works as expected.

```
   <ItemsControl KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" Focusable="False"  >
        ...

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lst" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"   BorderThickness="0"/>
    ..

   </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks Heena. I will award you the bounty after 17 hours as per the rules of stackoverfow.com. Jay Maharashtra.

Comment: You are Welcome..Jay Maharashtra !!

Answer (score 2):

Moving the focus from one ListBox to another within various items requires difficult logic. Instead you can use a single ListBox with grouping based on the Header. The GroupStyle Panel can be changed to stackpanel with horizontal orientation to achieve your UI. I tried like that and the focus works as expected,

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource source}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample? Because I get a blank listBox in my Output.

Comment: Please try this sample. https://db.tt/UnSN74Oe [Accept the answer if it helps you]

Comment: I have made some changes to your sample project. I have uploaded it : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bXzdtWFVMYnpEWXM/edit?usp=sharing But I got a small problem here. How do I decrease the space between two items of same group on its left & right side? Also I want to increase the space between two different groups.

Comment: Margin to ListBoxItem in ContainerStyle will control the spacings between items. Margin to WrapPanel will control the spacing between two groups. https://db.tt/UnSN74Oe Please accept the answer.