# How to move control/focus top and bottom based on button/hyperlink click in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Team,
I am new to WPF MVVM.
In my WPF window i have multiple grids(arranged vertically).
is that possible to change the focus/control based on button or hyperlink.

Say: we have 3 grids "Top Grid", "Middle grid" and "Bottom Grid".
When i am at 'Top Grid" i should be able to move to 'bottom Grid' on button/hyperlink click.
Similarly when am at 'bottom grid', i should be able to move to 'Top grid' on click of button/hyperlink.

Any assistance/sample is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: sure you can. You'll have to hook the calls for the button/links, and simply set the focus to the required element there....

Comment: Thanks, instead of setting the focus to the required element/field. Can be just scroll into the particular grid without setting the focus because i don't want to hard code the element also the elements/grid/groupbox may be disabled/readonly at times.

Comment: If your are working MVVM why not to use a simple converter?

Comment: yes, you can move different elements (scroll them into view), but we'll need more than what you've given us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209877/movefocus-from-one-listbox-to-another ..may be this will help